# expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct error C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

have a php code like this,going to convert it in to C#.

```
function isValid($n){
if (preg_match("/\d+/",$n) > 0 && $n<1000) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Here is my try,BUT error shown Error is  "expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct error C#"

```
public string IsValidate(string Item)
{
    string Result = Item;
   try
{
Result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(InputTxt, @"(\\)([\000\010\011\012\015\032\042\047\134\140])", "$2");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
}
return Result;
}
```

What is the error,Is there any other way to implement this better than my try ?
i got this snippet from here [code](http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-AddSlashes-StripSlashes-Escape-String.html)

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do. Are you trying to replace digits with value from variable Item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't define this method inside a class/struct that is why you are getting this error. You may define this method inside a class.

```
public class MyValidator
    {
        public string IsValidate(string Item)
        {
          //Your code here
        }

    }
```

Later you can use it like:

```
MyValidator validator = new MyValidator();
validator.IsValid("Your string");
```

Also you are missing semicolon at the end of the `Console.Write` statement, plus 'c' for Console should be in uppercase

**Edit:**
Since in your php code, it looks like you are trying to see if the string passed is an integer and it is less than 1000, you may use the `int.TryParse` like the following:

```
public class MyValidator
{
    public bool IsValidate(string Item)
    {
        string Result = Item;
        int val;
        if (int.TryParse(Item, out val) && val > 0 && val < 1000)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

In you main method you can do:

```
 static void Main()
        {
            MyValidator validator = new MyValidator();
            Console.WriteLine(validator.IsValidate("asdf123")); // This will print false
            Console.WriteLine(validator.IsValidate("999")); //This will print true
            Console.WriteLine(validator.IsValidate("1001")); //This will print false
         }
```

Comment: How to put my If condition here ?

Comment: @ChathuraRanasinghe, Are you checking if your string contains only numbers and its less than 1000 ?

Comment: Yes.,then how can i do this ?

Comment: Then in here my regular expression part missing know ? i mean my Result part .  Result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Item, @"/\d+/", "");

Comment: @ChathuraRanasinghe You don't need the regular expression part in C# code, `int.TryParse` will check it for you

Comment: But in that regular expression part  @"/\d+/"  thosethings not check it there know ?

Comment: What exactly do you need your IsValidate method to do?

Answer (score 3):

In C# a method must be placed inside a class or struct:

```
public class Validator {
  public string IsValidate(string item) {
   ...
  }
}
```

In this case I would probably translate it like this:

```
public static class Validator {   
  public static bool IsValid(string item) {
    int value;
    return int.TryParse(item, out value) 
           && value > 0 && value < 1000;    
  } 
}
```

Comment: How to put my If condition here ?

Answer (score 2):

You could define your function inside a static class such that you dont have to create an instance of it before invoking the function. Like,

```
public static class Validator
{
    public static string IsValidate(string item)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, you can call it using:

```
Validator.IsValidate("String to validate")
```

**EDIT:** You could then check that your function is returning what you expect by doing:

```
if(Validator.IsValidate("String to validate") == "Expected result") 
{ 
    /* Logic to be executed here */ 
}
```

Comment: How to put my If condition here ?

Comment: In a typical scenario, I would expect that a validation method return a bool (true or false). But either way, you can still apply an if statement like **if(Validator.IsValidate("String to validate") == "Expected result") { /* Logic to be executed here */ }**