# .NET IQueryable : Error expected class,delegate,enum,interface

Tags: c#, .net, azure, iqueryable

I am a noob to .NET and windows azure and trying to follow this tutorial:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_introtowindowsazurelabvs2010_topic2.aspx

when i try to declare an IQueryable property as follows:

```
public IQueryable<C1_Schema> C1_Schema
  {
    get
    {
      return this.CreateQuery<C1_Schema>("C1_Schema");
    }
  }
```

I Get an error : Error expected class,delegate,enum,interface,struct

This is the class where i declare the property

```
public IQueryable<C1_Schema> C1_Schema
  {
    get
    {
      return this.CreateQuery<C1_Schema>("C1_Schema");
    }
  }
    public class context : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceContext
    {
        public context(string baseAddress, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageCredentials     credentials)
      : base(baseAddress, credentials)
         { }
    }
```

C1_Schema class :

```
public class C1_Schema : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceEntity
{

    public String fname { get; set; }
    public String lname { get; set; }
    public double salary { get; set;}


    public C1_Schema()
    {
        PartitionKey = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MMddyyyy");
        // Row key allows sorting, so we make sure the rows come back in time order.
        RowKey = string.Format("{0:10}_{1}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.Now.Ticks, Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you created the class `C1_Schema`?

Comment: Show more code, including the class where this property is declared.

Comment: To which class belongs your property?

Comment: I have added both the code of the class where i declare the property and the C1_Schema class

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769866, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008119, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824194. The only stuff that can "live" in the outermost level (as direct members of the namespace) are _types_, and the types you can write are ... `class`, `delegate`, `enum`, `interface`, `struct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to declare the property outside of a class.  In C#, everything must be within a class.

Move the text of your property, like this:

```
public class context : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceContext
{
  public IQueryable<C1_Schema> C1_Schema
  {
    get
    {
      return this.CreateQuery<C1_Schema>("C1_Schema");
    }
  }
}
```

I would suggest you take some more basic C# tutorials first before trying to do something library specific like this.

Comment: A property can also be inside a `struct`, of course. Interfaces can define non-static properties, but the implementation is not in the interface (it's in the classes and structs that implement the interface).